# PHP script for sending MySQL DB submissions to a specified email address?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a DB that I've been manually checking for records each day. Is there a best practice for automating this process?

It seems like from similar questions that have been asked - there should be a script that inserts the new submission into a second table after it has been submitted. This second table will have a script to trigger the submission to be sent to specified email address. Is this correct? Are there any scripts already available out there? I can't seem to find anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are missing some info here, such as WHY are you checking records? Why is your form submission not just inserting the record into the table you need it to be in?

Comment: If you are using some sort of MVC framework you could override the model method which is inserting to send you an email everytime something is inserted.

However, it sounds like a reporting tool may be better? How about a daily cronjob to send you new entries rather than sending out every new entry?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this may not be a full answer more a 'primitive' suggestion. But you could just add a 'flag' to the current database you're using with a default of lets say 1. Then just update this for all current checked records to 0.

From here then you could have a PHP script that runs once a day, selects out everything from that table where the flag is 1. If it finds anything, format the result into how you wish to see it then attach the file you've created onto the e-mail to send to whatever address you require.

Once the e-mail is sent you then set the flag to 0 and repeat?